# Wiil my system configuration support Edius video editing software?

Tags: video-editor

I've heard some system requirement info about edius from video editing engineer that compare to intel, AMD is not good supporting processor for EDIUS and AMD can't withstand video rendering load of EDIUS.I know AMD is very good for video games. But why.....?
Below is my Desktop configuration.
  [image]

PROCESSOR: AMD FX 8350 -4.2GHz- 8 CORE- Wraith cooler
MOTHERBOARD: ASUS M5A78L-M/USB3
RAM: Kingston Hyper X Fury 2x4GB=8GB
HARDDISK= SATA 500GB 
OS: Windows 10 PRO

Comment: I would challenge the basic premise of your question that Edius is best for video editing.  I rarely hear it mentioned even if Grass Valley is big for live switching.   There are many other options you can learn which include software products both cheaper and more widely used.  I'd personally recommend starting on Resolve 14.  It is free, includes a solid NLE for starting out and is the industry standard for color grading (used on numerous major motion pictures).  It is by no means the only option, but Edius is an odd choice to call "best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can see it from on "system requirements" section their page:
https://www.edius.net/system_requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of that there would be a difference in processor performance is that the instruction set available on an Intel CPU (particularly something like an i7 or i9) may include some instructions that are not present on AMD chips that helps with optimizing more in to fewer instructions.  While both manufacturers do a lot of optimized instructions, software support for a particular set of calls could be more limited.

It's also possible that it's just ill informed users, but it is certainly potentially possible that the performance on a higher end Intel chip would be the performance of an AMD chip at the same clock speed.  That said, it's still very unlikely that it wouldn't work at all, it just might be a bit slower.  The system requirements for Edius appear to confirm this as well.